# Getting the header and body using google chrome extensions api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using Google's Chrome extension API to extract the ***header*** and ***body*** from a specific API post request fired from the browser. 
Currently, I'm using the below two functions to do that.

```
// Function One (Getting Body)
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
     // Body
     let REQUEST_BODY = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                        new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
                    },
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["requestBody" ,"extraHeaders"]);


// Function Two (Getting Header)
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
     // Header
    let REQUEST_HEADER =  details.requestHeaders
                        },
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},["requestHeaders" ,"extraHeaders"]);
```

How can I have just one event listener that would give me both metadata (header and body)? My goal is having this object `Data = {header: REQUEST_HEADER, body: REQUEST_BODY}`

FYI google chrome extension API doesn't have a single endpoint that supports both (header and body)

Comment: There's no way. You'll have to store the data from onBeforeRequest in a shared variable (a global variable for example) `bodies[details.requestId] = REQUEST_BODY` and then use it in onBeforeSendHeaders.

Comment: Interestingly, how can I then use onBeforeSendHeaders putting in mind there is always an addListener function attached to it?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's a problem. The data is saved in onBeforeRequest, then used in onBeforeSendHeaders.

Comment: Got it, I just don't understand how can I programmatically reuse the ```requestId``` (which I'll get from onBeforeRequest) with onBeforeSendHeaders to then get the headers. Do you have an example?

Comment: It'll be the same requestId in all listeners: `let body = bodies[details.requestId]`

Comment: where is ```bodies``` coming from in your example?

Comment: It's a "a shared variable (a global variable for example)".

Comment: So lets say the requestId is 1448 which I got from onBeforeRequest, how can I use the 1448 to get the headers from onBeforeSendHeaders? 
Are you saying Ill need to use the chrome.storage API for example to store everything there first?

Comment: No, you will use literally what I wrote `let body = bodies[details.requestId]`

Comment: I feel like I'm repeating my first comment over and over so I guess there must be some misunderstanding.

Comment: Hmm I did that within the ```webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener``` , but I got this error  ```Error in event handler: ReferenceError: bodies is not defined```! 

Do you have any end to end example that I can use, maybe a link? thanks again for helping btw!

Comment: To make a global variable define `let bodies = {}` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I decided to do this ```if (details.requestId === requestId) {do smth}```, the first variable is coming from ```onBeforeRequest``` and the second is coming from ```onBeforeSendHeaders```, this seems to be working. What do you think?

Comment: Whatever works for you.

Comment: Sounds good, Thanks so much @wOxxOm, the requestId is super helpful!